# How to increase the webview image to twice the original size?

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a webview whose work is to render an image. I want to display the image in the webview to twice the actual size(200% zoom). I dont want zoom option for that, just display the image as `2 X original image`. This is my code to display the image(The image is in encoded form)

```
webView.loadData(imageInbase64EncodedForm, "image/png", "base64");
```

Comment: @yuva `imageInbase64EncodedForm` is image in base64 encoded form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
webView.setInitialScale(200);
```

This will show the image as 2 times(200%) of the original image